# Removing index.php from CodeIgniter URLs in Windows

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting, xampp

I am running CodeIgniter on XAMPP on Windows.

I am having difficulties removing 'index.php' from my URLs. For example, myproject/index.php/users works but myproject/users returns a 404 error.

I have taken the following steps:

1) I set my .htaccess file to:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

2) In my config.php I have set:

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

3) In my httpd.conf I have ensured URL_Rewrite is enabled:

```
#LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
#LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
```

and all instances of AllowOverride have been set to:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Yet, it's still not working. Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `.htaccess` works for me:

```
    RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```